# Dart's DocumentFragment.html() constructor ignores standalone <tr> and <td> tags when parsing a piece of html

Tags: html, dart, dart-html

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td><!--Component_property:price--></td>
  <td><!--Component_property:size--></td>
  <td><!--Component_property:total--></td>
</tr>
```

Which I later intend to insert inside a table. Suppose it is contained within a string `s`. When I do this:

```
var fragment = new DocumentFragment.html(s);
print(fragment.innerHtml);
```

The output is this:

```
<!--Component_property:price-->
<!--Component_property:size-->
<!--Component_property:total-->
```

That is, all `<td>` and `<tr>` tags are stripped. This doesn't happen if the tags are within a `<table>` tag or with any other tags, which suggests that Dart simply doesn't like that the code inside the fragment is invalid.

What are the possible workarounds?

Comment: Is it the NodeTreeSanitizer that is stripping out the tags? Perhaps you could try pass a dummy sanitizer to the DocumentFragment constructor to see if this is the case.

Comment: How do I do that? I read about sanitizers, but it seems there's no way to ALLOW EVERYTHING. You can only allow individual tags and attributes.

Comment: I haven't used them before. I'm not really sure. I'd experiment with the NodeValidator class too. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using dart:html DOM classes to construct your `tr` and `td` elements.  You could do the following, for example:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var tr = new TableRowElement();
  tr.children.addAll([
      new TableCellElement()..text = 'x',
      new TableCellElement()..text = 'y']);
  querySelector('#myTable').children.add(tr);
}
```

This constructs a `tr`, adds a couple of `td`s to it and appends the whole thing to a `<table>`.

Comment: This wouldn't work in my case, since I need a complete freedom in what is in that piece of HTML. It's a template defined by a user.

Comment: And by 'complete' freedom, you really mean that the fragment could be anything? Even completely invalid markup? Or would you sanitize or process the user input in some way?

Comment: My apologies. By 'user' I mean a programmer who creates a template, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the validator. It's the implementation of the constructor:

> The HTML fragment is parsed as if it occurred within the context of a `<body>` tag, this means that special elements such as `<caption>` which must be parsed within the scope of a `<table>` element will be dropped. Use `createFragment` to parse contextual HTML fragments.

I think you should do something like:

```
DocumentFragment df = new Element.table().createFragment(s);
```

(Not tested.)

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.16.1/dart-html/Element/Element.html.html